# Question in translation of quel âge as-tu ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions

quel âge as-tu? . how does this sentence mean How old are you when as tu means do you have?How did this sentence formation took place?

Comment: Thank you for answering but have still not understood my question?

Comment: Ways of saying things in English do not correspond directly to ways of saying things in French. As I mentioned in my other answer, I would avoid trying to parse or translate expressions to/from French literally.

Comment: How should I understand it then?

Comment: Any reference book or web site I can use?

Comment: _Avoir_ is the infinitive for the verb meaning _to have_. _Avoir N ans_ expresses that someone is of a certain age. _Quel âge_ here refers to "what (lit. 'which') age", _as-tu_ is the inversion of _tu as_ for the sake of forming a question.

Comment: Ok thank you for helping

Comment: *Combien est-tu vieux ?* would be the literal translation of "how old are you?" but is not used in French at all, and might be considered offensive if it was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quel âge a-tu?** means what is already posted like: what age do you have?

**How was it formed** let's translate it.

Quel = What

âge = age

as = verbe *avoir* which is *to have*.

tu = you

Try making a sentence from these words, you'll get "What age do you have?"

It is also equivalent to **what is your age?** but that could be translated to **quel est ton(votre)  âge?** since *is* is verb *to be* which is the English counterpart of *être*.

Answer (score 1):

Quel age as-tu? would more translate to What is your age? or more literally What age do you have ? to make it easy for a beginner.

It could translate to How old are you? in the meaning, but it’s a harder for a beginner.